# iOS extension "Failed to find a valid app with bundleID" & "Error was encountered trying to find service extension"

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, ios-extensions

We have an extension in our iOS project (Broadcast Upload Extension). The extension works well when doing local builds, however whenever we do a TestFlight build a distribute it we encounter following exception (found in device logs):

> Error getting proxy for beta app with bundleID
>   com.foo.bar.screenshareextension: Error
>   Domain=ASDTestFlightFeedbackErrorDomain Code=5 "Failed to find a valid
>   app with bundleID com.foo.bar.screenshareextension"
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to find a valid app with bundleID
>   com.foo.bar.screenshareextension}

one more error lists:

> [com.foo.bar] Error was encountered trying to find service extension:
>   error=Error Domain=UNErrorDomain Code=1904 "Unknown application"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown application}

the bundle IDs are set correctly (meaning the container app has "com.foo.bar" bundle id while the extension has com.foo.bar.extensionname".

The extension is referenced through

`var bundleUrl = NSBundle.MainBundle.GetUrlForResource("Foo.iOS.ScreenShareExtension", "appex", "PlugIns");`

I can confirm actually that the extension appex file is physically in the archived file for distribution.

The only difference is that the min OS version is set differently in the container app & in the app extension. However when doing local builds this doesn't seem to matter.

What could be the reason for not being able to target the extension? (seems like it's missing?)

ps: we are using Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps: I encountered a similar error today, the reason is that the default build target of the notification extension is 13.6(the latest OS), while my testing device is in 13.5. After I changed the build target, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same error with native Swift code on iPhone 6 (12.4.8).

I'm still not sure what causes this bug, but for me it fixes only by changing device. On iPhone 8 (13.6) the absolutely same code works just fine, rebuilding for iPhone 6 and it's not even trying.